# ExtJS: Adding a grid panel to a table layout messes up the table column widths

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4.2, if I create a table layout panel with 2 columns and the inner panels have minimal content, then the column widths are all equal and the proportions are respected.

```
layout : {
        type : 'table',
        columns : 2,
        tableAttrs : {
            style : {
                width : '100%',
                height : '100%'
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's what that looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/blackfrancis75/yscjjbLf/1/

but if I then go adding content to the panels, say an `Ext.grid.Panel`, then the proportions of the columns get all messed up; they are no longer 50/50; it looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/blackfrancis75/kh8zr80h/1/

I've tried approaches like inner-panels, and `autoScroll` but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. 
What's the best way to 'force' the table layout to proportionally set the column widths regardless of their content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting :-

```
 tdAttrs: {
      style: {
           width: '50%'
      }
 }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/j76Log1x/)

Answer (score 0):

Table layout is very simple in Ext, it is just a wrapper around HTML table. Therefore I would recommend to use combinations of HBox an VBox layouts to achieve a table-like UI whenever you need anything more than simplicity of the HTML tables.